# How do I install a read-only lock on a file in Windows using C

Tags: c, windows, file, locking

I need to create a read-only lock on a certain file in Windows, in C. The lockf function is completely useless, as it creates an exclusive lock. I need to protect the file from writes, but multiple processes should be able to read it at the same time.

I cannot use CygWin or MINGW libraries, I am limited to the Microsoft APIs, which don't seem to have a decent fcntl. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean for a termporary period, then use CreateFile() with dwShareMode=FILE_SHARE_READ, else use SetFileAttributes()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock a portion of the file, use [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203.aspx).